# Encrypt database so system administrators have no access

Tags: php

I'm looking to develop an application for healthcare purposes using PHP. I want to encrypt the data so that nobody but the actual users to the application have access to the data.. not even system administrators. Does anyone have thoughts on a process to do this?

I did some research, and this seems possible where one user needs to access his/her data. But, I want to place emphasis on the fact that multiple users will need to access a set of data. Not just one user.

I realize that this could be done with a third common password amongst users, which can act as a salt.. but that doesn't seem very practical :)

Comment: If you can't trust your sysadmin then you're probably not paying them enough.

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt data use openssl rsa inside a browser. There are some implementation in js available. As fare as I know, the module is not running in every browser.

- Store private key inside a local db (html)
- encrypt/decrypt data inside browser
- build input form with js
- save encrypted data then on the server

But in that case even the php appl. has not access to the data :(

Comment: **And** your client has **full** access to the data.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Full? Why so? Every client has a private key to his own personal data only (but he's free to share as he sees fit), so that should be ok. Regarding PHP app accessing the data - that is more tricky. If only some of it is required / it is required some of the time thare are ways, like sending them from the client (I assume SSL) or sending akey from the client and not storing it anywhere (for something less sensitive), but this would require some more thinking.

Comment: @ Ignacio as the question mentioned, this is for healthcare purposes. System admin or not, I need to remove their access to the information.

Comment: @ wkaha, thanks for your answer, but I don't want to store anything locally. I know that's another road block, but it would require too much management and training

Comment: I guess the same approach would work, just instead of using local db you store asymmetric keys on the server, encrypted by some symmetric method, decrypted on client. I believe there is AES for JS and all the input needed is a password.